# find the min of the second index, then find the max of the third index of a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like this:

```
a = [[1, 3, 3], 
   [7, 2, 6], 
   [4, 2, 8]]
```

I want to transpose it and find the min of the second index, followed by the max of the third index, such that the resulting list I get is [4,2,8].

I have the following: `min(a, key=lambda x: x[1])` which helps me find the min of the second index, which is `2` but Python would pick `[7, 2, 6]`. I'd like Python to conditionally look for the max of the third index and then return the list.

Logic:

1. Find the min of the 2nd index from each nested list
2. Then find the max of the 3rd index from each nested list
3. Return the actual nested list from `a` that satisfies both 1,2

Comment: why would you delete your downvoted question and post it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of workaround solution, but code like:

```
min(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[2]))
```

Which finds minimal tuple consisting of second index and negated value of the third index (ergo: the biggest value from third index), returns results as you want it to:

```
>>> min(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[2]))
`[4, 2, 8]`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
a = [[1, 3, 3],
   [7, 2, 6],
   [4, 2, 8]]

min_no=min([i[1] for i in a])
max_no=max([i[2] for i in a])
for item in a:
    if min_no and max_no in item:
        print(item)
```

output:

```
[4, 2, 8]
```